# Using Apple's Internet Sharing with the second nic on my MacPro

Tags: networking, apple, bonjour

I want to plug a laptop into my server instead of using a switch.

When I check the button on my MacPro OSX 10.5.8 to share my internet connection on my second nic, it warns that it may affect other computers on the network and to contact my system administrator.  Is this just a warning to keep the uninitiated at bay, or is there something with bonjore that may cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, it's just a safety warning for people that may not understand what they are doing.